# Linq query to include a subtype

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In my model I have `Address` as a base class and `MailingAddress`, `Email`, and `Phone` as subclasses of Address.  A `Person` has an address so query to get a person who has an Oakland Mailing address would look like this:

```
var peopleInOakland = from p in entities.DbObjectSet.OfType<Person>()
                             from a in p.Addresses.OfType<MailingAddress>()
                             where a.City == "Oakland"
                             select p;
```

How do I also include the mailing addresses of the person in my query result? I know I should be using an Include, but I'm unsure of how to name the `MailingAddress` in the `.Include` argument.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a new type that has the specific type that you are looking for, like so:

```
var peopleInOakland = 
    from p in entities.DbObjectSet.OfType<Person>()
    from a in p.Addresses.OfType<MailingAddress>()
    where a.City == "Oakland"
    select 
        new { Person = p, Addresses = p.Addresses.OfType<MailingAddress>() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select into an anonymous type using the comprehension expression's local name:

```
...
select new {
  Persion = p,
  Address = a
};
```

Comment: I think he's asking for the syntax to populate the Person objects that are returned with the Addresses which are of type MailingAddress.  That said, I don't know how to do that off the top of my head :)

Comment: @Jonathan: if correct, then that is a trivial modification of either answer, but need clarification; as both answers do "include the mailing addresses[...]in the query result"